# Adding Custom colours to Excel sheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can anyone explain how to add Custom colours either using (rgb values or hex values ) to an excelsheet sheet(either in foreground or background) using Cellstyle in Apche poi to a Excelsheet(XSSF Workbook)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting custom colors depends on the kind of `Excel` file (Office Open XML format `*.xlsx` vs. BIFF format `*.xls`). And it might be different using different versions of `apache poi` because of deprecation.

Using Office Open XML format `*.xlsx` we can simply set new colors using constructor of [XSSFColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html). In `apache poi 4.0.0` `XSSFColor(byte[] rgb, IndexedColorMap colorMap)` can be used. `IndexedColorMap` can be `null` if no additional color map shall be used instead of the default one.

Using BIFF format `*.xls` only indexed colors are usable. But temporary overwriting some of the indexed colors is possible.

Following code shows both used for setting a cells's fill color. The used custom color is RGB(112,134,156). Using `HSSF`(BIFF format `*.xls`) the indexed color `HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIME` will be temporary overwritten.

Note, the following is tested and works using `apache poi 4.0.0`. No guarantee using other versions.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

public class CreateExcelCustomColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  CellStyle cellcolorstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellcolorstyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  byte[] rgb = new byte[]{(byte)112, (byte)134, (byte)156};
  if (cellcolorstyle instanceof XSSFCellStyle) {
   XSSFCellStyle xssfcellcolorstyle = (XSSFCellStyle)cellcolorstyle;
   xssfcellcolorstyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(rgb, null));
  } else if (cellcolorstyle instanceof HSSFCellStyle) {
   cellcolorstyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIME.getIndex());
   HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook = (HSSFWorkbook)workbook;
   HSSFPalette palette = hssfworkbook.getCustomPalette();
   palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIME.getIndex(), rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
  }

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellcolorstyle);

  FileOutputStream out = null; 
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelCustomColor.xlsx");
  } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelCustomColor.xls");
  }
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```