# How to set font color rgb in excel via apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to set font color in my project but I can't do it with RGB codes. I'm using this codes for now but I need to do it with RGB codes.

```
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();  
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet");  
    CreationHelper helper3 = wb.getCreationHelper();
    Font font = wb.createFont();
    font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
```

How can I set the font color with RGB codes? I looked some questions but I didn't make it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `XSSF` one can set font color using `XSSFColor`. And `XSSFColor` can be crreated from custom `RGB` values.

But  as you are using `HSSF`, this is not possible. In `HSSF` colors always needs to be palette colors. So if a custom color is needed, one of the other `HSSFPalette` colors needs to be overwritten.

Complete example which works for both, `XSSF` als well as `HSSF`. For `HSSF` it overwrites `HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIME` with `RGB` 222, 111, 222.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

public class CreateExcelFontCustomColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  byte[] rgb = new byte[]{(byte)222, (byte)111, (byte)222};

  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xls";
  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./Excel.xlsx";

  Font font = workbook.createFont();
  if (font instanceof XSSFFont) {
   XSSFFont xssfFont = (XSSFFont)font;
   xssfFont.setColor(new XSSFColor(rgb, null));
  } else if (font instanceof HSSFFont) {
   font.setColor(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIME.getIndex());
   HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook = (HSSFWorkbook)workbook;
   HSSFPalette palette = hssfworkbook.getCustomPalette();
   palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.LIME.getIndex(), rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
  }
  font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)30);
  font.setBold(true);

  CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setFont(font);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
  cell.setCellValue("test");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: OK, it works good. I have one more question, can I use it for cells foregroundcolor?

Comment: @demir5334: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117806/adding-custom-colours-to-excel-sheet-using-apache-poi/53120147#53120147.